# Allocating specific filenames to set of different output files in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating a set of PDFs that each include different information. I want to name the files according to the people who will be receiving the information. I am using `for` loops to run this:

```
 for (i in 1:nrow(files)){
   rmarkdown::render(input = "files_script.Rmd",
                     output_format = "pdf_document",
                     output_file = paste("Information_", i, ".pdf", sep=''),
                     output_dir = "directoryname/")
 }
```

The script works just fine, but the output files are simply numbered in my directory. I'd like to name them according to names in a column of my dataframe.

My data looks like this:

```
 Feedback Name    Surname
  xyz      John     Smith
  abc      Karen    Jones
```

I'd like to name the files by surname.

Comment: Could you add a small sample of what your dataframe looks like?

Comment: @BurlyPotatoMan done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your names are in two columns in a data.frame (I called it df here). You could use the `for` loop like this:

```
for (name in paste0(df$Name, "_", df$Surname)) {
  rmarkdown::render(input = "files_script.Rmd",
                    output_format = "pdf_document",
                    output_file = paste0("Information_", name, ".pdf"),
                    output_dir = "directoryname/")
}
```

I replaced `paste(sep = "")` with `paste0()` since it is doing the same thing.

Not sure though why you would do it that way. files_script.Rmd is always the same file. So it would be faster to render it once and then just change the name.

### Update

Since you said you want to keep the `i` as for loop variable, here is how you can do that:

```
names <- paste0(df$Name, "_", df$Surname)
for (i in seq_along(names)) {
  rmarkdown::render(input = "files_script.Rmd",
                    output_format = "pdf_document",
                    output_file = paste0("Information_", names[i], ".pdf"),
                    output_dir = "directoryname/")
}
```

`seq_along` is a safer way of doing `1:length(names)` in this case ([see this](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/writing-functions-in-r/a-quick-refresher?ex=14))

Comment: This does work as I'd hoped - thank you! - but now all the content has gone from the files themselves. I think this is something to do with [i]. In my markdown file, I have:

files_script$feedback <- feedback[i]

Sorry, this is the first time I've used for loops and I'm a bit out of my depth!!

Comment: I think you have to provide a more complete example of what you are trying to do. I don't understand where `files_script$feedback <- feedback[i]` comes to play. Is this within the files_script.Rmd? If so, you could use the `params` argument as described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html)

Comment: If the answer helped you to solve your problem, you should consider accepting it.

Comment: Sorry I've been away - this did solve the problem, thank you